# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR

Tags: php

I have the following error with my php code..

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in...`

My code is...

```
<?php if( !is_home()) or ( !is_archive()) { ?> 

(my code is here)

<?php ?>
```

The error is on the first line. I have tried googling this, but cannot see what I have done wrong.

Can you spot anything wrong with the above code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an editor with syntax highliting and brace/paren matching?  If not, find one, and your answer will become apparent.

Comment: Yes I use sublime but it shows nothing, perhaps I need a PHP syntax plugin

Comment: Sublime Text 2?  If so, when the caret is next to a paren or curly, it'll underline it and the matching one.  Hitting `Ctrl+M` will take you to the match.

Comment: Yes I have plugin, but the problem with the syntax above is that all the paren's did match, I just had too many!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
<?php if( !is_home() or !is_archive()) { ?>
```

Comment: thanks, I will mark this as the answer, as it does indeed resolve the error, however when I use this code, the rule above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `or` inside the `if()` like this :

```
if(!is_home() or !is_archive() ) {
```

More info here : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: As above, this removes the error, but my rule of displaying the content on certain pages no longer works